# ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) could not be identified as a valid source directory or file

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I get this error every time I run the `gcloud app deploy` command.

My `app.yaml` is in the same directory as where `manage.py` is.
I am also not working from Local disk C, am working from Local disk G and using Visual studio code cmd terminal.

```
ERROR: An app.yaml (or appengine-web.xml) file is required to deploy this directory as an App Engine application. Create an app.yaml file using the directions at https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml (App Engine Flexible Environment) or https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref (App Engine Standard Environment) under the tab for your language.

ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) [G:\] could not be identified as a valid source directory or file.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I can understand, you are running the "gcloud app deploy" command from the main folder of your G: local disk.

In order to deploy the app, your path should be the one that the app.yaml file is in or specify the path as a parameter as shown [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/deploy#EXAMPLES) in the first example when you run the "gcloud app deploy".

Answer (score 1):

Ran into the similar issue and wasn't really able to solve it in any way possible. Did all sorts of changes to that app.yml and `gcloud app deploy` would give me the `ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) could not be identified as a valid source directory or file`

Then I ran `gcloud --quiet app deploy app.yaml` and got this

```
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) [/Users/my/folder/ruby projects/Project/my_project/app.yaml] does not exist
```

Then I realized 2 things. The unescaped space in `ruby projects` folder in the route and the file should be called `app.yaml` not `app.yml` so it was messing up everything. Changed it to be `ruby_projects` and setup the `app.yaml` this time and boom!

```
Services to deploy:
.....
.....
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You are wrong the directory.
2. To make sure app.yaml path, you can include it into command line as below:

   `gcloud --quiet --project $PROJECT_ID app deploy app.yaml`