# ERROR: An app.yaml (or appengine-web.xml) file is required to deploy this directory as an App Engine application

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build, google-cloud-sdk

When I try deploying my Python code through Cloud Build to Google App Engine (GAE) I receive the following ERROR message:

```sh
ERROR: An app.yaml (or appengine-web.xml) file is required to deploy this directory as an App Engine application
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) [/workspace] could not be identified as a valid source directory or file.
ERROR: build step 0 "gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk" failed: step exited with non-zero status
```

Can someone explain what might be causing this error?

Comment: Where are the details?

Comment: Can  you share more on your code tree, your build steps,....

Comment: The structure is the source code,app.yaml and cloudbuild.yaml

Answer (score 0):

A Python app in App Engine is configured using an `app.yaml`, that contains CPU, memory, network and disk resources, scaling, and other general settings including environment variables. From looking at this error message your `app.yaml` appears to be missing. You can read more about how to configure your application here: [Configuring your App with app.yaml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml)

Comment: Has the .yaml been linted for syntax errors? I agree with the users above. We would need to see:
   - your `app.yaml` files,
   - which Google App Engine (Standard or Flex) you are using?,
   - which Python are you running?
   - how are you deploying it?
- your code directory structure as pointed out by @guillaume-blaquiere yesterday

If you update your question with this information we can guide you.

Comment: runtime: python3
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /
  script: ether-api.py

Comment: I am using appengine standard and python3

Answer (score 0):

Ran into a similar issue, to see my how I finally solved this issue (in my case). See
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75851704/8056390)